# ADO.NET SCOPE_IDENTITY() Возвращает NULL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio, ado.net

Что-то всё работало, а потом поломався!
Данными база заполнена. Всё работало.
Запрос Get_Kod_Zakaz возвращает null, в SQL работают запросы.

```
  private void Load_Form(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conK = Util.ConnectBD.Get_KDB();
            SqlParameter Kod_Sotr = new SqlParameter("@Kod_S", Proxy.Author_Class.Get_Kod_Sotr());
            SqlCommand Insert_Zakaz = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Zakaz (Status, Kod_Sotr) values (5, @Kod_S)", conK);
            Insert_Zakaz.Parameters.Add(Kod_Sotr);
            SqlCommand Get_Kod_Zakaz = new SqlCommand("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conK);
            Insert_Zakaz.ExecuteNonQuery();
            kod_z = Convert.ToInt32(Get_Kod_Zakaz.ExecuteScalar());
            //при запуске добавлять запись в таблицу заказов
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся!
Решить проблему помогло использование **IDENT_CURRENT('имя_таблицы')**.

Как я узнала из интернета, что при использовании SCOPE_IDENTITY() возникают проблемы, т.к. эта функция берёт идентификатор из всех таблиц. Возможно, там происходят ещё какие-либо процессы, о которых я не знаю. Хотя, вроде всё работало, да и других действий с БД на момент исполнения этого метода не должно быть.

Кому интересно, можете почитать: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Ну, визуально, вроде, все верно.

Проверьте, есть ли в данной таблице колонка с типом `IDENTITY`. Идентификатор могу отключить.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand Insert_Zakaz = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Zakaz (Status, Kod_Sotr) values (5, @Kod_S)", conK);
```

в этой строке значения должны содержать **' '**  Values (**'5'**, **'@Kod_S'**)"

Comment: Нет, не должны. 1) 5- это число 2)У него параметаризованный запрос